# How to fix phpmyadmin access after deleted all users

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

i deleted all user's account by mistake

[image: this picture which users i deleted]

after that while i try to login i got this.

[image: error event]

my config.inc.php (have this part)

```
 /* Authentication type and info */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
 $cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, By Setup xampp In another pc, and copied (C:\xampp\mysql) to the target pc that have error.